# So many false statements in the comments

Tags: discussion

Do you guys purposefully leave comments downgrading answers in the comments? Over the past few days, I have given answers that were right and people decided to argue in the comments. I feel like it is an attempt to discredit some answers and get points by having the commenter's answer viewed as right by the question asker.

Comment: 90% of an answer to a question pertaining to a legal matter is how the person who answers a question can argue their point and back it up. The law isn't black and white, there can be several interpretations of a specific law. The legal field is an adversarial process in determining what argument can stand their ground against scrutiny. I wouldn't take comments as an attack on your answer, comments are a tool to help other users understand your answer, or to improve your answer. Other users don't have the ability to read minds and if one user doesn't understand your answer chance are they

Comment: aren't the only ones.

Answer (score 14):

One of the purposes of comments is to allow users to say something on the logic or factual basis of an answer, and the comment can be supportive or work against an answer. If you find the comment to be valid, you should modify your answer to take account of the comment. If you find the comment to be ultimately wrong but based on a reasonable premise, you should probably modify the answer to show why the consideration given in the comment is not applicable in the present case. For instance, if you know of applicable case law that you didn't originally cite, you should cite that case law and explain why it is relevant. You can just ignore comments if you want, but they can be helpful in case you are not legally omniscient, or in case your answer is not self-evidently correct. Take them as an opportunity to improve your answer.

Comment: I understand that sometimes commentators could be wrong, but some of it is obvious abuse.

Comment: I haven't seen such comments, but you can report abusive comments to the moderators.

Comment: Hey @Putvi, user6726 is correct - comments are intended to be a way of clarifying and checking the answer. If someone comments and challenges your answer (or part of it) then you can either respond in the comments, or modify your answer to take the comment's argument into account. If someone is not being nice in the comments, then you can flag it for moderator attention - but merely disagreeing with you is not likely to be removed, unless otherwise warranted.

Answer (score 5):

Comments need to be made to an answer when it is inaccurate or incomplete.

Comment: But, false comments don't need to be made to correct answers.

Comment: @Putvi It is incredibly frustrating to have to deal with your repeated incorrect statements about the law, your lack of accurate citations or often any citations, and so on. When someone who understands the law tells you that you are incorrect as may posters in this forum do, you should assume that you need to really research and justify your point of view.

Comment: I have research and am someone who understands the law. It is frustrating when you guys say things like doors must be unlocked from the outside as part of the law as david whatever did, or when you say things like you can bring up old restraining order claims or that non electing doesn't refer to votes.

Comment: You don't know me and its incredibly frustrating if you blindly say you know more than me. It's also arrogant and rude. I made it to the top 3% in two weeks. You don't know if I'm a judge or someone who's never been to court, so don't assume you know more than others, because you have provided several wrong answers and won't drop it. I do provide links and you try to skirt around the issue.

Comment: @Putvi What is your background? I'm a lawyer who was admitted to the practice of law in 1995 who has practice continuously since then. I was a cum laude graduate of the University of Michigan law school and a senior editor on the Michigan Journal of International Law. I'm admitted to practice in New York State and Colorado. I've been a partner in a private law firm. I've been a professor of estate planning, and I've taught lots of continuing legal education courses. I've never tried to be anonymous. https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrew-oh-willeke-a14a373/

Comment: I'm not faulting you for graduating cum laude and think you did well there, but that does not mean you know everything. I was a clerk for a friend who is a judge in Indiana because I planned on becoming a lawyer and work part time for the local Sheriff/Courts when they need extra help. I didn't want to just knock you for no reason, but I've have seen tons of OP cases and you were just clearly wrong there and you were without question wrong about the stock thing. I have nothing against you, but you just aren't right always, not to say you never are.

Comment: My day job is IT work though. I worked on the computers that process financial transactions, before going out on my own, so I know from personal experience that the stock part is not correct.

Comment: @Putvi I had to say it, but your self-assessment of what you know is lacking.

Comment: I see your profile says you do legal work for estates and same sex couples. I don't doubt that and am sure you are good at that, but that isn't 100% of the law.

Comment: You had no idea what you were talking about, as my links show and you smarted off to me for no reason. Please apologize. Thank you.

Comment: I have to agree with ohwilleke. He takes the time to back up what he says. You on the other hand seem to just spout out whatever opinion you have. I've noticed that many times you are flat wrong. It usually doesn't take long to see how wrong when one searches for actual law. Just because you worked for a sheriff doesn't mean you know the law. Law makers, judges and lawyers usually do. I don't think anyone owes you an apology. But I've seen people take comments you make that were plain flat wrong if you look up the law and they've acted on just your opinion. You might owe an apology to them.

Answer (score 3):

Neither law nor Law.SE are the place for "my answer was right" with no authority. ('I work for...' is authority if the question asks about that specific area only, but not otherwise, whatever may fill in the blank). Comments asking about points the answer does not consider, pointing out contrary authorities, and criticizing the internal logic of answers are fulfilling precisely the correct function of comments, whether or not you agree with them. Comments that just say "This is wrong" are out of place, as much as comments that say "This is right"; but criticism and disagreement are as fundamental in the law as they are in rational argument.